# How to use JSON::Validator with Perl 5.8?

Tags: json, perl, jsonschema

There are not many modules which offer functionality to validate JSON files when a JSON schema is provided.

I found out that
[`JSON::Validator`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Validator)
has a dependency on the `Mojolicious`. And, `Mojolicious` has dependency on `feature` pragma which was introduced in Perl 5.10.

Is there any way to avoid using `feature`, or using it in Perl 5.8?

Comment: You've misdiagnosed the situation. `JSON::Validator` depends on `Mojolicious` which requires `perl` 5.10.1.

Comment: Did you try [JSV::Validator](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSV::Validator)?

Comment: [*Which versions of Perl are supported by Mojolicious?*](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/FAQ#Which-versions-of-Perl-are-supported-by-Mojolicious)

Comment: If you're developing a significant project then you really should upgrade your Perl installation to a version that is still supported. Perl v5.8.0 is fifteen years old now, and so is probably older than your computer system.

Comment: `JSV::Validator` does not seem to work well. It does not have proper documentation and `validate` method is always returning "0".

Comment: That is not what I observed, at least with the code from the module's synopsis. Also, it seems to me there isn't a need for much documentation: Pass the schema and data (not JSON string) to `validate`.

Comment: Thanks! `JSV::Validator` is now working well after providing schema and data to `validate` method instead of their string values.

Comment: @vp8 You're welcome to write an answer to your own question, which you can later accept as the answer. Might be helpful for others.